# How to solve stbi_load error of "no SOI"?

Tags: opengl, stb-image

I'm loading a picuture by `stbi_load`, but there was an error of `no SOI`. I had used the picture in another project and it was loaded successfully. So I think the path of picture and the picuture is valid. But I don't know why the error occured? Here are some of the main code:

```
// Texture2D is a class of textures 
Texture2D ResourceManager::loadTextureFromFile(const GLchar *file, GLboolean alpha){
    // create texture object
    Texture2D texture;
    if (alpha){
        texture.Internal_Format = GL_RGBA;
        texture.Image_Format = GL_RGBA;
    }
    // load picture
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char *image = stbi_load(file, &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (stbi_failure_reason())
        std::cout << stbi_failure_reason() << std::endl;
    // generate texture
    texture.Generate(width, height, image);
    // free image
    stbi_image_free(image);
    return texture;
}
```

I use `loadTextureFromFile("./Data/awesomeface.png", GL_TRUE);` to get the texture. And `stbi_failure_reason()` returns `no SOI`. When I debug the project in VS2013, the memory of `image` is valid but display `characters in a string are invalid`. Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

from an old project i found on my disk. i'm not used to C++ anymore, so i'am not sure if it has sth to do with your problem, but i think i am looking at c++ code?

```
  auto textureBuffer = stbi_load("graphics/texture.png", &width, &height, &bitppx, 4);
```

and i found something about corrupted .png files with stb

> Some PNGs look enough like a JPEG that the JPEG file format test will
>   break with the "no SOI" error instead of rejecting the image as a
>   JPEG.

https://github.com/nothings/stb/issues/787

solutions:

- check your if your filepath is correct
- check if a different .png works
- use  auto textureBuffer instead of unsigned char pointer

Comment: bitppx is actually the number of channels, not the number of bits per pixel.

Comment: Yes, this is c++ project. And I use OpenGL4.0. The path is right. I reuse a jpg image and use auto instead of unsigned char pointer.  Although the `no SOI` error solved, the data of image become error code and memory access conflicts arisen.It's confusing.

Comment: I change the last parameter of `stbi_load` to 4,  the data of image still is garbled code.

Comment: from the stb_i.c doc on supportet filetypes:
QUICK NOTES:
      Primarily of interest to game developers and other people who can
          avoid problematic images and only need the trivial interface
      JPEG baseline (no JPEG progressive)
      PNG 8-bit only

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the library (current one is 2.27) seems it was fixed:

https://github.com/nothings/stb/issues/787