# Problem with loading files in C++ program

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2019, loading, stb-image

When I am starting my program to run using VS2019 local debuger everything works perfectly fine. When I am opening .exe file, my program cannot find these files. I am trying to launch my program from x64/Debug folder in my project repo folder.

[Screenshot from my console debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pKXz.png)

My first thought were about path. I included full path to my .PNG file, but my program cannot find it anyway.

Here is the code I am using with loading texture file:

```
Texture texSpecularMap;
    if (!texSpecularMap.LoadPNG("assets/textures/container_specular_map.png"))
    {
        Debug::logWarning("Failed to load texture: assets/textures/container_specular_map.png");
    }
```

```
bool Texture::LoadPNG(const char* filePath)
{
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(filePath, &width, &height, &nChannels, 0);

    if (data) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    stbi_image_free(data);
    return true;
}
```

Don't look at my stupid warning messeges. I know I should specify a variable storing path.

Comment: What's the working directory of the launched application? Are you sure your path is correct?

Comment: When running under the debugger, there is often a different current working directory than  when running in release mode, and you are using a relative path. Is the `assets` directory in the same directory as your executable file?

Comment: My folder tree looks like this:
I have main folder called cppGameEngine
Inside I have folders: ReallyX(which is my project name)/assets
where I am storing PNGs
and x64/Debug where is my .exe file

Comment: My advice is to use the `stbi_failure_reason()` to get the information on why the load is failing like in this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495090/how-to-solve-stbi-load-error-of-no-soi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495090/how-to-solve-stbi-load-error-of-no-soi)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When loading images with stb_image, stbi_failure_reason() is you best friend.
The best thing you can do is give a absolute path to the file.